# Reading custom plist causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, plist

I have a custom plist file that looks like this:

[image: custom plist file]

I know the data is there (I displayed it using NSLog).  My problem is I'm getting a runtime error: **object can not be nil** when reading the first line after initializing *hexColors with this code:

```
NSString *pListPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ColorSchemes" ofType:@"plist"];

// Load the file content and read the data into the array
NSDictionary *colorsDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath];
//  NSLog(@"\ncolorsDict: %@", colorsDict);

NSMutableArray *hexColors = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[hexColors addObject:[colorsDict objectForKey:@"buttons"]];
[hexColors addObject:[colorsDict objectForKey:@"calendar"]];
[hexColors addObject:[colorsDict objectForKey:@"leftGrid"]];
[hexColors addObject:[colorsDict objectForKey:@"topGrid"]];
[hexColors addObject:[colorsDict objectForKey:@"dataGrid"]];
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the addObject code (it used to work, no changes have been made).  Can somebody please help me figure this out?

Comment: Changes must have been made. There is NO way the code you posted ever worked with the posted plist. Either the structure of the plist changed or the code changed. Most likely you added the 2nd level dictionaries to the plist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not mistaken `colorsDict` is the root dictionary. Its keys are `Spring, Autumn, etc.`. The keys `button, calendar, leftGrid`, are part of the dictionaries that you can access through the season keys.

You would need to do (for example)

```
NSDictionary *realColorsDict = [colorsDict objectForKey:@"Spring"];
[hexColors addObject:[realColorsDict objectForKey:@"buttons"]];
[hexColors addObject:[realColorsDict objectForKey:@"calendar"]];
[hexColors addObject:[realColorsDict objectForKey:@"leftGrid"]];
[hexColors addObject:[realColorsDict objectForKey:@"topGrid"]];
[hexColors addObject:[realColorsDict objectForKey:@"dataGrid"]];
```

Let me know if this solves your problem :)

Comment: I see what you're saying... I need to make some changes to the code... I'll get back to you...

Comment: The problem was the singleton was not being set properly in AppDelegate...fixed that and now it works... thanks for your help; I appreciate it.  SD